# Can't find where modsecurity.conf and .load file are located?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using LUbuntu, which is Ubuntu 15.04
I have apache2 installed, and I compiled modsecurity from source code.
I start apache as usual:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

and then I checked what modules are loaded:

```
apachectl -M
```

all the modules loaded are the ones who have `*.conf` and `*.load` files located in this folder:

> /etc/apache2/mod_available/

The `mod_security2.so` file goes after the compilation to `/usr/local/modsecurity/lib/mod_security2.so`.
The good news for me is that it is also copied to `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`
but I still can't find the config and load files in

> /etc/apache2/mod_available/

I tried this command :

```
sudo a2enmod mod_security2.so
```

and the answer was :
ERROR : mod_security2 does not exist!

Should I create these files myself?
I am waiting for the sooner help.

Thanks,

Comment: Create a soft link like: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/modsecurity/lib/mod_security2.so /etc/apache2/mod_available/mod_security2.so`

Comment: Any reason to install mod_security from source instead of using the repository?

Comment: Yes, @pauloAlmeida the reason that it's for the open source contribution to modsec, I want to add and change things in the code, if I want to surely have to build it from source code.

Comment: @heemayl I was just about to post the same suggestion as an answer but I see you’ve already posted it as a comment. I thought it’d be rude to do so without giving you the opportunity to post it as an actual answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thanks being being nice..I haven't got any reply from OP regarding that so did not post an answer yet..i will do so..

Answer (score 0):

On CENTOS / RHEl7 the path is:  `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`